# System not matching monitor resolution

Tags: windows-7, resolution, amd-radeon

I have ATI Radeon HD7970, Dell monitor with max resolution: 1920x1200 and Windows 7 64bit.

On starting computer:

1. BIOS - all displayed OK
2. Windows loading - all displayed OK
3. Logging in screen - not displayed - monitor is telling me, that best resolution is 1920x1200. It looks like graphics card is using too high resolution.

All I can do is put the computer to sleep, then wake it. Then all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are right and the resolution is set to high:

- Boot in safe mode (via <kbd>F8</kbd>)
- Remove the Catalysts drivers.
- Reboot. (Windows will now show a 800x600 screen).
- Reinstall the catalyst drivers and reboot

On the next log-in you can select your 1920x1200 resolution.
Just test it first before confirming.

[image]

One other possible cause it **not** a too high resolution but to too high **refresh rate**.  You can find the settings for that under [Advanced settings]

Comment: I have set good resolution.